# Folium plot returns 'TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable'

Tags: python, html, folium

In my script below, the Folium plot returns 'TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable'. It appear there is a problem with the last line of the script because when i comment it, it runs, but when i uncomment it, i get the TypeError. I need to plot the file to html or jpg.

```
import pandas as pd 
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster  
for_map = pd.read_csv('datasets/sum_loads.csv')
max_amount = float(for_map['total_offs_sum'].max())
hmap = folium.Map(location=[51.5, -0.1], zoom_start=7)
hm_wide = HeatMap( list(zip(for_map.latitude.values, for_map.longitude.values,     for_map.total_offs_sum.values)),
                   min_opacity=0.2,
                   max_val=max_amount,
                   radius=17, blur=12, 
                   max_zoom=1, 
                 )
hmap.add_child(hm_wide)
locations = list(zip(for_map.latitude, for_map.longitude))
cluster = MarkerCluster(locations)
hmap.add_child(cluster)
hm_wide.save('output_plot.html')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Maybe this helps: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1208

Answer (score 1):

In lines with Christian's suggestion most probably your for_map.total_offs_sum.values is integer. Just try to convert that to float. For example

```
hm_wide = HeatMap(list(zip(for_map.latitude.values, for_map.longitude.values,for_map.total_offs_sum.values.astype(float))),
                       min_opacity=0.2,
                       max_val=max_amount,
                       radius=17, blur=12, 
                       max_zoom=1, 
                     )
```